# Query the occupied memory in dolphindb

Tags: memory, dolphindb

Query the occupied memory in dolphindb

I find the memory for some nodes is full. But I don't konw which operation consumes these memory. Is there a way to query them?

Answer (score 0):

step1

pnodeRun(clearAllCache) //Release the cache of all nodes (the memory occupied by the defined variable is not released)

step2

```py
pnodeRun (objs) //View the variables defined on each data node and the memory occupied (not shared) 

pnodeRun (objs{true}) //View the variables defined on each data node and the memory occupied (shared)
```

Use udef(), undef all, variable name=NULL to release memory occupied by non-shared variables;

use undef("sharedTable", SHARED) to release memory occupied by shared variables.